# How To Set Variable Value In If

Tags: batch-file

Hi I make simple batch file now what I tried to add correct answers number at the end but it keeps saying zero because the variable values are not changing when the answers are chosen. Here is my code below

```
@echo off
title Game One
color 1f
::#############################
:one
set correctn=0
set correctn2=0
cls
echo What is 2 + 2?
echo.
echo.
echo A) 6
echo B) 4
echo C) 49
echo D) 17
echo.
echo.
echo Type the correct answer.
set /p ch1=
echo.
echo.
if not defined ch1 (goto one)
if %ch1%==A goto no
if %ch1%==A correctn=0
if %ch1%==B goto yes
if %ch1%==B correctn=1
if %ch1%==C goto no
if %ch1%==C correctn=0
if %ch1%==D goto no
if %ch1%==D correctn=0
pause>null
::#########################################
:no
cls
echo Sorry, that answer is incorrect.
echo.
echo.
echo The correct choice was B, which was 4.
pause>null
goto two
::#########################################
:yes
cls
echo You are correct. Congratulations.
echo Press any key to continue.
pause>null
goto two
::##########################################
:two
cls
echo What is 100 divided by 2?
echo A) 45
echo B) 50
echo C) 90
echo D) 17
echo.
echo.
set/p ch2=
echo.
echo.
if not defined ch2 (goto two)
if %ch2%==A goto no2
if %ch2%==A correctn2=0
if %ch2%==B goto yes2
if %ch2%==B correctn2=1
if %ch2%==C goto no2
if %ch2%==C correctn2=0
if %ch2%==D goto no2
if %ch2%==D correctn2=0
echo Invalid Choice, Please Try Again!
pause>null
::#################################
:no2
cls
echo Sorry, that answer is incorrect.
echo.
echo.
echo The correct choice was B, which was 50.
pause>null
::########################################
:yes2
cls
echo You are correct. Congratulations.
echo Press any key to continue.
pause>null
goto end
::######################################
:end
set/a correct=%correctn% + %correctn2%
echo Number of answers correct was %correct%
pause>null
```

So how to change variable value in if statement if already variable exists?

Comment: you are missing **set** keywords.  EG use **if %ch1%==A set correctn=0**

Comment: No sorry, I tried it but it did not work. But I did something that made it work, the problem is my if's, i changed it so that it set the values before goes the next page. But u helped me figure out the set so thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `set` a variable first and then `goto`. As currently written, your script goes to a label `yes` first. Hence, `if %ch1%==B set correctn=1` line is never reached:

```
if %ch1%==B goto yes
if %ch1%==B set correctn=1
if %ch1%==B goto yes
```

Moreover, [`IF` command](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) string comparison is case sensitive without `/I` switch; try the following:

```
if /I %ch1%==B (set correctn=1&goto yes)
```

I'd suggest using (Windows native) [`CHOICE.EXE`](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) instead of `set /p` for a single key-press user input, e.g as follows:

```
CHOICE /C abcd
IF %errorlevel%==2 (
    set correctn=1
    goto yes
) else (
    set correctn=0
    goto no
)
```